# Help with Big-O homework

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

"er" is the Danish equivalent of "is" in English. I need some help with the square root one. Additionally, it would be nice to know if the other ones are correct. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this fact that $\log(n) = O(n^k)$ for any constant $k > 0$ and $k \in \mathbb{R}$. $k$ in your case is $\frac{1}{2}$. Hence, $\sqrt{n}$ **is not** $O(2\log(n))$.

Comment: But I think I remember that sqrt(x) isn't a polynomial. In other words $x^{0.5}$ isn't a polynomial.

Comment: @AlexanderNielsen it doesn't matter. It is true for any $k > 0$ (not just for integers).

Comment: Okay, thanks. By the way, do you happen to know whether my other answers are correct?

Comment: +1 for posting that it is homework. -10 for posting homework.

Comment: I don't get it, what is wrong with asking for help with homework? @gnasher729